# Can't update language of doc file

Tags: java, properties, apache-poi, document

I've extracted the `POIXMLProperties` from my document(template created locally) and I see the language property exist with a value (the system language) but I can't modify it as the `POIXMLProperties` don't let you do it as described in the [api doc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties.html).
Here is the full code:

```
public InputStream updateMetadata(String extension,
                                    InputStream source,
                                    Date created,
                                    String creator,
                                    String language) throws IOException {
    
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("editor-document", ".tmp");
    try (POIXMLDocument document = getDocument(source, extension);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile))
    {
      POIXMLProperties props = document.getProperties();
      POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProps = props.getCoreProperties();
      coreProps.setCreator(creator);
      coreProps.setCreated(metadataFormat.format(created));
      document.write(fos);
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to change the language property, please?

Note that I set the doc template language to none (from tools > options inside the doc)

Comment: If you set a language using Word, save the file, rename the `.docx` to `.zip` and unpack, which xml file inside the zip holds the language setting?

Comment: the `docProps/core.xml` contains the language: ```<dc:language>en-GB</dc:language>```

Comment: Btw the language is set to the system language not the one I chose in the document !!

Comment: It's not ideal but I think you can get at set that via [the underlying properties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties.html#getUnderlyingProperties--)